# How to pick selected rows from a tensor, regardless of dimension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor (`tensorflow.Tensor`) `A`, and I would like to form a new tensor containing certain rows from `A`, that is, `A[i,:,:,...,:]` for selected values of `i`.

Problem is I don't know before-hand how many axes `A` has. So how can I write this operation?

Comment: `tf.gather(A, i)` will give what you need

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `tf.gather()` is for. See the example code below:

```py
x = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), [2, 2, 2])

# This is using tf.gather() on a 3D tensor.
print(tf.gather(x, [1]))
```

The result is:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]], dtype=int32)>
```

```py
x = tf.reshape(tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), [2, 4])

# This is using tf.gather() on a 2D tensor.
print(tf.gather(x, [1]))
```

The result is:

```
tf.Tensor([[5 6 7 8]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=int32)
```